# Local high scores reporting/Display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Please can anyone refer me to a tutorial or help me out with this problem. I wish to display high scores  and other games statistics at game Over but I don't seem to get a headway despite looking at tutorials and trying stuff out. I don't seem to understand how to use NSUserdefaults to achieve this.

My codes are as follows:

Gameplaylayer.mm

```
- (id)initWithHUDLayer:(HUDLayer *)hudLayer {
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        score = 0;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSDictionary *defaultArray = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                        nil]
                                                                forKey:@"Scores"];
        [defaults registerDefaults:defaultArray];
        [defaults synchronize];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void)gameOver:(id)sender{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *HighScores = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[defaults arrayForKey:@"Scores"]];

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < [HighScores count]; i++)
    {
        if (dist >= [[HighScores objectAtIndex:i] intValue])
        {
            [HighScores insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:dist] atIndex:i];
            [HighScores removeLastObject];

            [defaults setObject:HighScores forKey:@"Scores"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            NSLog(@"Saved new high score of %i", dist);
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    score += (int)delta;
    dist = score - 18;

    if (!gameOver ) 
    {
        if (!lives)
        {
            gameOver = true;
            [self gameOver];    
        }
    }
}
```

my game over layer is as follows

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) 
    {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        CGSize windowSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        NSArray *HighScores = [defaults arrayForKey:@"Scores"];

        CLabelTTF *title = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"high scores" fontName:@"Courier" fontSize:32.0];

        [title setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height - title.contentSize.height)];

        [self addChild:title];

        NSMutableString *scoresString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < [HighScores count]; i++)
        {
            [scoresString appendFormat:@"%i. %i\n", i + 1, [[HighScores objectAtIndex:i] intValue]];
        }

        CCLOG(@"scores saved %i", dist);

        CCLabelTTF *scoresLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:scoresString dimensions:CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height / 3) alignment:CCTextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Courier" fontSize:40.0];

        [scoresLabel setPosition:ccp(screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2)];

        scoresLabel.color = ccc3(0, 0, 0);
        [self addChild:scoresLabel z:9];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your code, please look at this small example below.

Ok, that's saving new score, assuming you have GameController singleton, where `scores` mutable array is declared and `currentScore` in that singleton also displays current player's score.

```
-(void) saveScores {

    GameController * controller = [GameController sharedController];

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        if([[[controller.scores objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue] == controller.finalscore)
        {
            break;
        }
        if([[[controller.scores objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue] < controller.finalscore) {
            for(int j=5;j>i+1;j--) 
            {
                [controller.scores replaceObjectAtIndex:j-1 withObject:[controller.scores objectAtIndex:j-2]];
            }

            NSMutableDictionary *newEntry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:controller.finalscore],@"score",@"Local player",@"name", nil];
            [controller.scores replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newEntry];
            break;
        }
    }
    controller.currentScore=0;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:controller.scores forKey:@"OurScores"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

You can see, that we are saving updated scores in NSUserDefaults. So, at our game start we shoul load them. I added this code to GameController init method:

```
- (void) loadScores {
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OurScores"] == nil) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *empty = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"score",@"empty",@"name", nil];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            [scores addObject:empty];
    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Loading scores");
        scores = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OurScores"];
    }
}
```

And that's how we can show this scores using cocos2d:

```
-(void) drawScores {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        CCLabelTTF* score = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[controller.scores objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30];
        score.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
        score.position = ccp(115, 180-i*35);

        CCLabelTTF* score2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:
                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[controller.scores objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"score"] intValue] ] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:35];
        score2.anchorPoint=ccp(0,0);
        score2.position = ccp(280, 180-i*35);

        score.color=currentClr;
        score2.color=currentClr;

        [self addChild: score z:3 tag:i];
        [self addChild: score2 z:3 tag:i+15];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems, some of which just break with convention but all together they make your program quite unreadable. I have not been able to make sense of it. You are not using comments, nor are you telling us, what exactly is not working.

For instance, you might consider following the convention of having instance variables start with small letters, reserving capitalized names for classes. It is generally a bad idea to give misleading names, such as calling an `NSDictinoary` "defaultArray". Also, try to use empty lines more sparingly to structure your code for better readability.

That being said, this is how you set a default value:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:scoreArray 
                                         forKey:@"Score"];
```

I see you know how to retrieve the score.

As for your updating routine, consider that it is normally not a good idea to modify the array your iterating through (in your particular case it could still work, but it is not guaranteed). Also, there is no need to store the whole array in the loop. Just save it once you have contructed the complete new high score array.

Otherwise your code is working, right?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I really do not understand what you are talking about...

Comment: You did not state what is actually not working. Please tell us.